# Accessing template variable in directive's host listener

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Given the following, is it possible to access 'habitCellInfo' from the template in the onvalueChanged host listener?

```html
<div *dxTemplate="let habitCellInfo of 'habitEditCellTemplate'">
  <dx-select-box
    (onValueChanged)="
      onHabitEditorValueChanged($event, habitCellInfo)
    "
    [dataSource]="habitsDataSrc"
    [value]="habitCellInfo.data.habit"
    pimDxSelectBox
  >
    <dx-validator>
      <dxi-validation-rule
        pimDxiValidationRule
        rule="noun"
      ></dxi-validation-rule>
    </dx-validator>
  </dx-select-box>
</div>
```

```js
import { DxSelectBoxComponent } from 'devextreme-angular';
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';

import {
    Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, NgModule, OnInit, Renderer2, Self
} from '@angular/core';
import { addSelectBoxCustomItem } from '@pim/common/shared-dx/util';

import { PimDxModules } from '../modules/pim-dx-modules.module';

@Directive({
    selector: '[pimDxSelectBox]',
})
export class PimDxSelectBoxDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() acceptCustomValue = true
    @Input() dataSource!: DataSource
    

    // Inject an instance of select-box
    constructor(
        private elRef: ElementRef,
        @Self() private readonly selectBox: DxSelectBoxComponent,
        private renderer: Renderer2,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.selectBox.acceptCustomValue = this.acceptCustomValue
        this.selectBox.dataSource = this.dataSource
        this.selectBox.grouped = this.grouped
        
    }

    @HostListener('onValueChanged', ['$event'])
    editorValueChanged(e: Event) {
        // HOW DO I 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an input to your directive and pass the cell info from the containing template.

In the directive:

```js
@Input() pimDxSelectBox: any;
```

In the containing component:

```html
[pimDxSelectBox]="habitCellInfo"
```